# How to prevent `tabularx` run a macro in trial runs?

Tags: tabularx, expansion, spreadtab

By the following code I can set some tags in table's rows, and keep track of the desired rows in a macro.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{spreadtab}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcounter{tabline}

\makeatletter
\gdef\ctag#1{\@ifundefined{c#1}
{\expandafter\xdef\csname c#1\endcsname{\thetabline}}{\expandafter\xappto\csname c#1\endcsname{,\thetabline}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{>{\stepcounter{tabline}\thetabline}cc}}
 & @ a\\ @\ctag{1}
  & @ b \\
   & @ c\\ @\ctag{1}
   & @ d\\
\end{spreadtab}

\csname c1\endcsname
\end{document}
```

[image]
Everything is fine, but when I use `tabularx` instead of `tabular` something goes wrong and the result will be repeated two/three times. see the pic below.

```
\begin{document}

\begin{spreadtab}{{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\stepcounter{tabline}\thetabline}cX}}
 & @ a\\ @\ctag{1}
  & @ b \\
   & @ c\\ @\ctag{1}
   & @ d\\
   & @ e\\ @\ctag{1}
   & @ f\\ @\ctag{1}       
   & @ g\\              
\end{spreadtab}

\csname c1\endcsname
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm so confused why it happened in case of using `tabularx`?!

P.S. cc makes two repetitions and cX makes three ones.

Comment: it isn't clear what you intend to happen but `tabularx` sets its body multiple times in trial settings to find the best columns widths, at least two but in general an unknown number of times as it iterates until it converges on a solution. Unless there is linebreaking within the column cells then tabularx shouldn't really be used, never use it for numeric data tables.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry for inconvenience, I modified the question. As you mentioned, when I use `cc` in `tabularx` it makes two copies and when I use `cX` it makes three ones. So is there any way to use my `\ctag` macro in this case?

Comment: the number of iterations depends on the table content, not  on the column specification (tabularx with cc would be an error anyway) you could make ctag only accumulate on the final run not on trial runs, but I suspect not using tabularx is the correct thing to do here

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Appreciate your concern. I've also changed the title, I think this new title makes more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tabularx` is designed to find a good width for linebreaking within the table cells, so is not designed for tables of data. Using `tabular` as in your first example is therefore probably the best approach however if you really want to use `tabularx` just accumulate the data in the final typesetting run, not when it is making trial runs to calculate the column widths

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{spreadtab}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcounter{tabline}

\makeatletter
\gdef\ctag#1{\ifx\@footnotetext\TX@trial@ftn\else
\@ifundefined{c#1}
{\expandafter\xdef\csname c#1\endcsname{\thetabline}}{\expandafter\xappto\csname c#1\endcsname{,\thetabline}}%
\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{spreadtab}{{tabularx}{10cm}{>{\stepcounter{tabline}\thetabline}XX}}
 & @ a\\ @\ctag{1}
  & @ b \\
   & @ c\\ @\ctag{1}
   & @ d\\
\end{spreadtab}

\csname c1\endcsname
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, I really wanted to accumulate the data at the last run and your solution do it well. ;)